# Composer load class without Namespace

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, amazon-mws

Amazon's MWS PHP client library is just a zip file without any namespace, Is there a way to use this library with Laravel application or with any application which uses composer for its dependency management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just create your own library directory in your Laravel app. I usually keep mine just inside `app` directory and call it `Libraries`. Dump the source files inside a folder such as `AmazonMWS`.

`.config.inc.php` comes with an autoloader but it won't be used. Instead you could probably just open your `composer.json` in your Laravel project and tell it to autoload your new Library directory targeting the config. Ex:

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/Libraries/AmazonMWS/Client.php"
    ]
}
```

Make sure `config.inc.php` is accessible at the `AmazonMWS` root.

Then run `composer dump-autoload` to regenerate the autoloaders. If done properly then you should be able to instantiate any of the MWS classes without a namespace.

In your Controller, include the following `use`:

```
use \MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Client;
```

Now you can call your service as expected:

```
$config = [...];

$service = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Client(
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    APPLICATION_NAME,
    APPLICATION_VERSION,
    $config);
```

Or just omit `use \MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Client;` and instantiate directly with namespace prefix, your choice.

Comment: I put Amazon Classes inside `app\Libraries\AmazonMWS`
And updated composer.json with following:
`"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
   "files": [
   "app/Libraries/AmazonMWS"
  ]
 }`
And i also run `composer dump-autoload` but when i started the server its giving error
_Failed opening require 'app/libraries/amazonmws' in c:\...\autoload_real.php_

Why do we add this line?  `"classmap: [ "database" ]`

Comment: It was just a sample from one of my `composer.json` files. Check my updated answer and try that once.

Comment: I did exactly that and Laravel is producing this error **Class 'MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Client' not found**

Comment: Try to prefix the class with \, so `new \MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Client`.

Comment: I don't do this sort of thing often so I'm not 100% sure...you may have to potentially add each Class file path into the autoload files array. Try to add that class to the array and give it a shot.

Comment: Think I got this working on my end. See updated answer.

Comment: @ShreyanshPanchal did you figure this out?